# Не работает код

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(#yap_button).click(function() {
   $(#yap_button).addClass('hidden');
   $(#hidden_box).removeClass('hidden'); 
  });  
});
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему не работает?

Comment: Спасибо, я опять попался на самом простом :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки добавьте для селекторов